# Quasar QSelect does not start on selected option

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, quasar-framework

I have a Vue 3 / TypeScript app built using the Quasar UI library.

One of the components I am trying to build is an international phone input with a country dropdown using QSelect.

My problem is that when the QSelect options are first opened it shows the top of the options list, not the currently selected option.

If I close the options and reopen again, it is correctly scrolled to the selected option. This is the behaviour I expect when first opening it.

Why does it work on the second open and not the first?

As shown below, I have tried to solve this using various methods in `handleOnCountryOptionsShow` but they have no effect.

```Vue
<template>
  <q-input ref="inputElement" v-model="inputNumber">
    <template #prepend>
      <q-select
        ref="countrySelectElement"
        v-model="countrySelected"
        :options="countryOptions"
        option-value="id"
        option-label="name"
        :virtual-scroll-slice-size="countryOptions?.length"
        :virtual-scroll-item-size="countryOptionItemHeight"
        @popup-show="handleOnCountryOptionsShow"
      >
        <template #option="scope">
          <div>
            <div
              class="country-item q-pa-sm cursor-pointer"
              :class="{ 'country-option-focused': scope.focused }"
            >
              {{ scope.opt.name }}
            </div>
            <q-resize-observer
              @resize="hanldeCountryOptionResize"
            ></q-resize-observer>
          </div>
        </template>
        <template #selected-item="scope">
          <div v-if="scope.opt">
            {{ scope.opt.name }}
          </div>
        </template>
      </q-select>
      <q-separator vertical />
    </template>
  </q-input>
</template>

<script lang="ts" setup>
import { nextTick, onMounted, ref } from "vue";
import { QSelect, QInput, QResizeObserver } from "quasar";

const inputElement = ref<QInput | null>(null);
const inputNumber = ref<string>();

const countrySelectElement = ref<QSelect | null>(null);
const countrySelected = ref<{ id: number; name: string }>();
const countryOptions = ref<{ id: number; name: string }[]>();
const countryOptionItemHeight = ref(0);

const generateCountries = () => {
  const countries: { id: number; name: string }[] = [];
  for (let i = 1; i <= 250; i++) {
    countries.push({ id: i, name: `Country ${i}` });
  }
  return countries;
};

const hanldeCountryOptionResize = (size: { height: number; width: number }) => {
  if (!countryOptionItemHeight.value) {
    countryOptionItemHeight.value = size.height;
  }
};

onMounted(() => {
  // Make the countries list
  countryOptions.value = generateCountries();
  // Set a country on load
  countrySelected.value = countryOptions.value[111];
});

const handleOnCountryOptionsShow = async () => {
  await nextTick();
  const index = countrySelectElement.value?.getOptionIndex();
  console.log("index", index); // This shows the correct index
  countrySelectElement.value?.reset(); // This doesn't fix the problem and seems to have no effect
  countrySelectElement.value?.refresh(); // This doesn't fix the problem and seems to have no effect
  countrySelectElement.value?.updateMenuPosition(); // This doesn't fix the problem and seems to have no effect
  if (index) countrySelectElement.value?.scrollTo(index); // This doesn't fix the problem and seems to have no effect
};
</script>

<style>
.country-item:hover,
.country-option-focused {
  background-color: #eeeeee;
}
</style>
```

**Here is a screenshot showing the problem:**

[image]

**Here is a working live example:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/quasarframework-yqsvxg?file=src/pages/IndexPage.vue

**UPDATE:** Upon further testing, I think it has to do with the `#option` slot. It works ok if I remove that. But I still want to use it somehow.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out.

The problem was the value I had for `virtual-scroll-item-size` was reactive, with an initial value of 0.

When actually it should be a static value that is close to the minimum size of an item. `QSelect` uses that value to load the initial list display. And since it was starting at 0 all heights were initially estimated as 0 height, causing it to display incorrectly.

Changing this to `virtual-scroll-sticky-size-start="37"` and removing the `q-resize-observer` fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this component
[image]

The q-select is wroking fine without the q-resize-observer component. I resized my browser and everything is working fine without the component. Also, don't forget to remove the 'hanldeCountryOptionResize' function as well.

happy coding :)